# Node.js Express ES6 app.address is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

First,***Merry Xmas to all online people*** at this current time...

I am learning to rewrite some basic code from ES5 to ES6 ..

A basic Node.js Express server written with ES5 js

**ES5**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
var express = require('express');
var router = require('./routes');

var app = express();
app.use(router);

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

module.exports = server;
```

running fine !

Now I rewrote it using ES6 js

**ES6**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes';

const app = express();
app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  var port = app.address().port; ?? 
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
});

export default app;
```

running it,  I am getting an error ..

```
app.address is not a function
```

But if I change the app.listen block, then it runs OK ...
what is the problem with the app.address() ?

**ES6**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import express from 'express';
import router from './routes';

const app = express();
app.use(router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

`app` and `server` are different objects. `app` isn't supposed to have `address` property.

As [the reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) states,

> The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object

Given that `listen` callback is regular function, `this` context is `http.Server` object inside:

```
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', this.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with te Express version, take a look on the migration guide:

https://expressjs.com/es/guide/migrating-4.html

Answer (score 0):

This will work as expected.

```
 const server=app.listen(3000, function () {
    let port = server.address.port; 
      console.log('Example app listening on port %s!', port);
    });
```

From [express docs:](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)
The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object and (for HTTP) is a convenience method for the following:

```
app.listen = function() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```